# How to install HP sound driverin ubuntu?

Tags: drivers

I'm using hp pavillion laptop and recently i installed ubuntu on my laptop. So my problem is ** How to download sound driver on my laptop?**

Comment: Why do you think you need a sound driver? Nothing in the question tells me that. I also do not see a version of Ubuntu stated.

Comment: Usually you don't. The kernel should support your soundcard. You should elaborate **why** you want to install a driver. Execute `inxi -A` and `pactl list sinks` in a terminal and copy the output into your question - use the [edit](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1395248/edit) link

Answer (score 1):

to install all needed drivers on your system you need to open `additional drivers` and select drivers that you need.
after that apply your changes , it will automatically install on your system.
also, ubuntu use `pulse-audio` and `ALSA` to play sound in the system,
take a look at it